# Is there a compatibility mapping of Spark, hadoop and hive

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

Its confusing to understand version compatibility between different versions of Spark and hadoop. Similarly for Hadoop and hive.

Is there any table that can be followed to know which version of one is compatible with which version of other ?

Comment: The pre-built Spark packages on the download page explicitly says "for Hadoop 2.6 and later", so what's the confusion there? Probably same for Hive, but the "asparagus chart" by Hortonworks is what they officially support.  http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/asparagus-chart-hdp24.png

Comment: @cricket_007 Thanks for the reply. Thats helpful. I am adding the chart you provided as an answer to my question. Thanks again.

Comment: It's not a compatibility chart, though, just what is used in each release of HDP

Answer (score 0):

The compatibility chart as shared by @cricket_007

http://hortonworks.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/asparagus-chart-hdp24.png

Comment: What about the ongoing compatibility for Spark with other libraries. Currently I using Spark 2.2 and not able to get working Hadoop 2.8.1 for saving some data to Azure blob storage from Spark. Refereing @cricket_007 who gave the chart earlier